# Dynamic JSON Generation in Java

Tags: java, json

I have to send a batch of instructions in JSON data format as below:

```
{
   "batchId": "123456",
   "instructions": [ {
        "instructionId": "1",
        "customer": {
             "iban": "abc",
             "name": "abc"
          }
        },
        "instructionId": "2",
        "customer": {
             "iban": "abc",
             "name": "abc"
          }
        }
       .
       .
       .
 .. . . .. 
     ]
}
```

Now, i will fetch multiple records/instructions from the database via query, which I will use to generate the JSON data-set as per the format above.

**What I have researched:** I have traversed many solutions and thought of my own that I shall create an object class of Instruction mapping with setters and getters. I shall use a loop through each record and set values of object fields from database via setter and add entry that complete object entry to JSON via getters.

I will continue this approach until the records are read completely.

**My question is:** Is this solution efficient and best one to deal with such requirement or any other suggestion?

Please suggest? Any sort of code snippet or help is appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is the one generally used. Add each of such instruction object created to an array list.

Comment: Have a look at Jackson and Gson. These libraries are used to map classes to a json structure. I would start with creating a Batch class which contains a batchId and a list of instructions...

Comment: The case is resolved thanks. I have used Gson as preferred by @jaylordibe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [com.google.gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for that.

Create the Instruction object and then add the fields and annotate the field with `SerializedName` if you are mapping a different json name to your java field(E.g. instruction_id to instructionId).

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Instruction {
    
    @SerializedName("instructionId")
    private String instructionId;

    @SerializedName("customer")
    private List<Map<String, Object>> customer;

    public String getInstructionId() {
        return instructionId;
    }

    public void setInstructionId(String instructionId) {
        this.instructionId = instructionId;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(List<Map<String, Object>> customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

And then you can map your json to your instruction class.

```
Instruction instruction = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create()
        .fromJson(json, Instruction.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the GsonBuilder what shall be my **json** variable?

Comment: as far as this approach is concerned. I think this approach generates the object from json. I need to create a Individual JSON string from large dataset.

Comment: You need to use the item in your instructions array as a json variable.

Comment: But this mapping is converting my JSON to Mapper Class. I want to generate JSON from the Class object.

Comment: So you wanted the reverse? I think you can use this. 
JsonObject jsonObject = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(yourClassObject);

Comment: Yes reverse. Let me try!

Comment: One more thing that you have created the customer as **<Map<String, Object>>** what shall I set in that Object for setter?

Comment: You don't need to manually set on that. Google gson will take care the mapping if you will use this.

Instruction instruction = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create()
        .fromJson(json, Instruction.class);

Comment: In case of toJSON(json). I have to set the object first. How I will do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216467/discussion-between-jaylordibe-and-jawad-dev).

Comment: // Get instructions from database
List<Object> instructionsFromDatabase = instructionService.getInstructions();
// Convert instructions from database to json
JsonObject jsonObject = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(instructionsFromDatabase);

Comment: Yes its resolved. Just one problem that the sequence of keys is not in order in the instructions array! Is there any way of sequencing them?

Comment: Can you give me sample keys that should be sequenced? The json output will just depend on the data from your database. I suggest that you use order by in your database query.